# What is the difference between CIColorCube and CIColorMatrix?

Tags: ios, core-image

I'm developing a filter for iOS following a recipe. This recipes asks to increase the red value in the blue channel and to increase the blue in the red channel (100% on both).
I've done this using ColorMatrix. I'm considering only the VectorR, VectorG and VectorB.
My ColorMatrix became something like this:

R: 1 0 1

G: 0 1 0 (no changes)

B: 1 0 1

The problem is that the result is different from Photoshop. The previous filters had the exact same result, it looked almost identical to the photoshop result, but this color changes are not working.

To fix this, I'm thinking about using CIColorCube instead of CIColorMatrix.
From this perspective (change red value in red channel, change blue value in the blue channel), is there going to be any difference in the results? I don't know the difference between CIColorMatrix and CIColorCube.

Thank you